# ANALYZE TABLE gives NULL for all statistics in Spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
var df2 = spark.read
.format("csv")
.option("sep", ",")
.option("header", "true")
.option("inferSchema", "true")
.load("src/main/resources/datasets/titanic.csv")


df2.createOrReplaceTempView("titanic")
spark.table("titanic").cache()
 
spark.sql("Analyze table titanic compute statistics for all columns")
spark.sql("desc extended titanic Name").show(100, false)
```

I have created a spark session, imported a dataset and then trying to register it as a temp table, upon using analyze command i gett all statistics value as NULL for all column.

```
+--------------+----------+
|info_name     |info_value|
+--------------+----------+
|col_name      |Name      |
|data_type     |string    |
|comment       |NULL      |
|min           |NULL      |
|max           |NULL      |
|num_nulls     |NULL      |
|distinct_count|NULL      |
|avg_col_len   |NULL      |
|max_col_len   |NULL      |
|histogram     |NULL      |
+--------------+----------+
```

Can someone suggest what is it that i am doing wrong.?
The thing I noticed is if i make a new table

```
spark.sql("create table newtitanic as select * from titanic")
spark.sql("Analyze table newtitanic compute statistics for all columns")
spark.sql("desc extended newtitanic Name").show(130, false)
```

this will fetch me statistics for all columns.

Answer (score 0):

The `ANALYZE TABLE` statement can be used for tables only. It doesn't support views.

Comment: So a better answer would be to add how it works such stats for a temp view!

Comment: Thanks @Gabio for answering. I have a follow up question since i have to get stats for a delta table, the only way i know of is to use spark.sql("Analyze ... ") for this i have to run createOrReplaceTempView function, else it errors out with unresolved dataframe name. What should be the approach? to gets stats on delta table